# Putting all configuration in uri in mongoid.yml does not connect ruby with mongo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, docker, mongoid

Here is the *mongoid.yml*, which works fine:

```
development:
  clients:
    default:
      database: dbname
      hosts:
        - hostname:27017
        - hostname:27018
      options:
        user: 'a.b@user.com'
        password: 'asdfg1234'     
        ssl: true
        ssl_verify: false
```

But If I put this information in a uri and comment out those, the ruby app cannot connect to mongodb:

```
development:
  clients:
    default:
      uri: mongodb://a.b%40user.com:asdfg1234@hostname:27017,hostname:27018/dbname?authSource=admin&ssl=true&ssl_verify=false
      # database: dbname
      # hosts:
        # - hostname:27017
        # - hostname:27018
      # options:
        # user: 'a.b@user.com'
        # password: 'asdfg1234'     
        # ssl: true
        # ssl_verify: false
```

It shows the following error:

```
MONGODB | SSL handshake failed. MongoDB may not be configured with SSL support.
```

Any help to solve this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me: Added self signed ssl certificate, configured mongoid.yml, put all the information in uri, added the uri in mongoid.yml as an ENV var.